# How to write a app for Android in the same way as JFrame

Tags: java, android, layout

I installed the ADT plugin for Android for Eclipse, and I don't like it.

I would like use my own Grid Layout the way I want and design windows by code (the same way as JFrame in Java, because I already know how to do this) not by click and drag.

How to do this in Android?

Comment: Do you try to look for the official tutorials and samples on http://developer.android.com

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but forget about the JFrame. That's a subclass of kava.awt.Frame and the java.awt package doesn't exist in Android.

Comment: @11684 could you give me some info about it?

Comment: They say http://developer.novell.com/yes/48606.htm KAWA is the opposite of what I am looking for. I just want to have sth what works the same way as JFrame. I want to code it I don't want to have any kind of Graphic Interface letting me move my buttons etc. I want to use layouts as I know them BoxLayout, Grid etc.

Comment: You can code them in XML, there's a switch under the graphical editor in the ADT (if you selected an XML document).

Comment: I consider this a legitimate question and don't understand the -1 vote. 1+ up-vote to counteract the previous down-vote.

Comment: @Hovercraft: I did not delete any tags. I must have edited just seconds after the OP changed the tags. BTW: Some of the downvotes (not by me) may have been caused by the original wording of the question.

Comment: Is there any way to run the android app not on the AVD?(beside phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't think it's a great idea to write the UI code in java, here's how you would do it.

First, you'll want to look at the `android.view.*` and the `android.widget.*` packages in the [Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) docs.

Everything the the Xml corresponds to a `View` (or Subclass).  So, if you see `LinearLayout` in the Xml, then there will be a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) java component as well.

So, in your `Activity's` `onCreate()` method, where normally you'd just set the content resource xml view, you can instantiate a Widget and set it directly.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
   TextView tv = new TextView();
   tv.setText("Hellow World);
   setContentView(tv);
}
```

You might also need to the set the `LayoutPararms` as well, since most widgets need to know if they should wrap content or fill the parent.

Many of the Layout widgets are analogous to Swing Containers, ie, they accept children, so you can call addChild() with another view to create a widget hierarchy.

This should be enough to get you started.

As a final note, I'd like to reiterate that while you can build the complete UI in Java code, the Xml layout does offer some other benefits.  For example the Xml layouts allow you to support multiple screen sizes, or different layouts (landscape vs portrait, etc), which is much harder to do (but not impossible) in Java.  Also, you might be tempted to think that because the Views are in Xml, then they will be "slow" to be created on the device.  But, Android optimizes the Xml resources, and in fact, I don't think they are even Xml at the time they are compiled into your App.  So the resource Xml files are very efficient, and writing direct Java code for the Views probably won't get your much extra in terms of performance.

Comment: Layouts are compiled to a binary XML format, which is very compact. I suspect that the code for a layout will be bigger than the data representation so that in large apps it could be burdensome.  With a hard limit of 24Mb on app memory footprint, you should be afraid. Even Java has effectively deprecated Java coded layouts: AWT and SAF are barely supported at this point. The Netbeans Platform strongly encourages XML. You have to move with the times.